# PathJS elegant way of ignoring rest of the url

Tags: javascript, path.js

I am using `path.js`. I have a service like `/foo/bar/baz` and I use `baz` as parameter. So my router is like:

```
Path.map("#/foo/bar/:baz").to(function(){
    //call the service
});
```

However sometimes I need a url like: `/foo/bar/baz/ignore/whatever/etc/bla/bla`. But `/whatever/etc...` part is not predictable as we may have more than one parameter.

So is there a possible way to get rest of url as a parameter after a certain level. I need something like:

```
Path.map("#/foo/bar/:baz(/*rest)").to(function(){
    var params = this.params['rest'] ? this.params['rest'] : this.params['baz'];
});
```

in this case rest = ignore/whatever/etc/bla/bla

Comment: missing quote is normal ?

Comment: sorry, my bad. it was just psudo code to show my need. thanks.